# teradata sql - aggregating time until reset?

Tags: sql, sum, teradata, reset

I am writing a query in Teradata and need to sum the time it takes for an object to hit a number. for example... for numbers 0-4, I want to sum the time since the object reached 3 or higher.
I have started with

```
SUM(time)
OVER (PARTITION BY object
      ORDER BY object, number
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 1 FOLLOWING)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

sample data...`IDnum     WS       times
               1         0        8012
               1         1        6254
               2         3        10225
               2         1        5896
               2         4        5485
               2         0        7482
               3         1        5487
               3         2        5214`

WS rangs from 0-4, and i need to sum the time since refurb for each ID, and reset the time count when the WS is a 3 or higher (3 or higher indicates a refurb). i.e I need a "time since last refurb" if that makes sense .

desired results would be `IDnum     WS     times     time since last refurb
                        1         0        8012             14266
                        1         1        6254             14266
                        2         3        10225            16121
                        2         1        5896             16121
                        2         4        5485             23668
                        2         0        7482             23668
                        3         1        5487             23668
                        3         2        5214             23668`

or something similar

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You'll certainly have to make use of the 'RESET WHEN' clause. Posting sample data will help.

Comment: Your current SQL is invalid syntax and you explanantion is hard to follow. Can you show some example data and expected result?

Comment: Can you edit once more and share what your expected result for this sample data would be. It's still not clear what you are wanting as a result.

Comment: How is the data ordered?

Comment: ordered by idnum

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() function to generated the sequence based on that do the cumulative sums :

```
select *, sum(times) over (partition by grp) as time_since_last_refurb
from (select *, sum(case when ws >= 3 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by seq) grp
      from (select *, row_number() over (order by idnum) seq
            from table
           ) t
     ) t;
```